# setRetainInstance(true); doing it wrong?

Tags: android, xml

I think an illustration of what happens in my app is best for this question.

After the user logs in they are brought to the MainActivity. This contains an `ActionBar` with tabs, by default one tab is selected and the user sees....

```
    container1              container2

CompanyName: <EditText> |               |
ProjectName: <EditText> |     Welcome   |
   <SearchButton>       |               |
```

When the user fills out those forms and clicks the search button they see...

```
  container1             container2

   <ListView>       |                  |
   BasicInfo        |     Welcome      |
   Assessment       |                  |
   Signature        |                  |
```

When the user clicks "Assesment" they see

```
   container1             container2

   <ListView>       |     Question#1   |
   BasicInfo        |     Question#2   |
   Assessment       |     Question#3   |
   Signature        |     Question#4   |
```

Now when the Assessment `fragment` inflates it performs an `AsyncTask` and creates the `Views` for the questions from `JSON`. Now when the user is on this screen I do not want a screen orientation change to perform the network request and `AsyncTask` again. So I put the `setRetainInstance(true);` in the Assessment `Fragment` like this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_assessment, container, false);
        ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
        infoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        allRadio = new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
        allImageButton = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
        allSpinner = new ArrayList<Spinner>();
        allEdit = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        allCheck = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

        new Load().execute();
        setRetainInstance(true);
        return view;
    }
```

Yet when I flip my screen in the Assessment `Fragment` not only does it not save the layout it returns me to the parent `Activity` that looks like this

```
    container1              container2

CompanyName: <EditText> |               |
ProjectName: <EditText> |     Welcome   |
   <SearchButton>       |               |
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. It could be my `fragment` in `XML` is named incorrectly or maybe the containers are named incorrectly. Here is there code.

**Container XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:background="@drawable/green_gradient"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/twoglobe_line"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Assessment Fragment XML**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/basic_info_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/twoglobe_line"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gen_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

So am I expecting an unrealistic outcome from the line `setRetainInstance(true);` or am I just doing it wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *not only does it not save the layout* - you can't save views across a configuration change, that's a sure way to have a memory leak. *it returns me to the parent Activity that looks like this*  probably because you don't save somehow the new state of the fragment(I'm assuming that you change the same fragment). Regarding `setRetainInstance()` you could make a small test and see which of the callbacks get called:)

Comment: @Luksprog so in other words you would say I **am** doing this wrong and my expectations **are** unrealistic?

Comment: Actually, setRetainInstance does retain the layout and all the values of the fragment. Check documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean) . Now, you can make that work, but requires a little more work on the activity side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first screen, i would use a seperate activity. CaseyB's answer is really good, and it is actually how I hand it as well (now, when you have alot of orientation changes, and a few things on the backstack, you'll get forcecloses, but its inevitable). What I would do is the first screen, make it its own activity, then call a second FragmentActivity and make the fragment on the Left side static (meaning define it in XML). That way you dont have to worry about it. Then, you can focus on the right fragment. If you set the setRetainInstance, then you dont need to worry about recreating the views. But, if it goes to the backstack, then you lose everything. It never calls onDestroy, only onDetach. And onCreate is only called the first time the fragment is created. So, I would avoid using onCreate at all, and focus on using onActivityCreated() and onAttach() to instantiate values and whatnot

Update -
Use the onCreate() method to set setRetainInstance(true) and call your JSON and network code to create the views. Its important to do it here, so that it only gets called once. 
This should work entirely for orientation changes and going back and forth between fragments (the backstack will work, just you cant set it to retainInstance while in the backstack. That was a typo on my part).

Then, any other code you want called when the fragment is brought back up, use onAttach() since onCreate() wont be called since it was never destoryed

Then, in order to get control of your items again, you cant use getActivity().findViewById(), you have to use this.getView().findViewById(). I dont know why that is the case (since you would think that it would be attached to the activity viewgroup,  but it isnt). That should be the only hiccup you should hit. Outside of that, it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks again Shaun. I follow you up to the point of  *make the fragment on the Left side static (meaning define it in XML).* When you start getting into the backstack I get lost. If you want to add a simple implementation of how I could use `setRetainInstance()` in the actual fragment once the views are loaded I will accept it as the correct answer

Comment: If you need further help, send me an email at compguru910atgmail . I can send you a simple project to illustrate it a little better.I had alot of problems with this too when I first started working with fragments.

Comment: e-mail sent. If you don't mind, can you invite me to chat? I have a couple quick questions right now I could bounce off you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the right way but this is the way I do it and it works for me.

In my layout I don't have the fragments themselves I just have containers that will hold them.  Then, at the start of my app I see if any of my fragments are already loaded (they will be in the tablet layout) and if not I look to see if there is anything in the savedState bundle. If that Bundle is null then I know my app is just starting for the first time and I can load my "home" fragment.  Otherwise I have put a key in there in `onSaveInstanceState()` to let me know which fragment to load. So I'll have the FragmentManager load one of those into the container.

Comment: This is very clever, I like it. This is also very similar to how my app is set up. Different layouts for tablet, containers, not actual fragments until I load them etc. This may be an alternative to what I'm trying but I wouldn't necessarily say its an answer to the direct question of "Am I being unrealistic or Am I doing this wrong?". Either way thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

I actually have still not figured out how to properly use this `setRetainInstance()` method. I had to resort to temporarily using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize
```

in my manifest. I have heard from multiple people that this is discouraged and the **wrong way** to do this. So this topic is still open and I will be accepting any answer that correctly illustrates how I should be using this code properly.